# Parsing Twitter list id/username from url (C# or JavaScript)

Tags: c#, javascript, twitter

I have Twitter list url, like `https://twitter.com/{list-owner-screen-name}/{list-slug}`

What is the best way to get `list-owner-screen-name` and `list-slug` from that url?

I obviously can use regexp to parse it , but I am not sure what is the valid regexp here (generally speaking this is kind of ad-hoc solution). I also suspect that there is a better way to do this (maybe some sort of api/lib can help me).

It does not matter where this parsing/conversion will occur. I can do this both on server-side (C#) or on client side (JavaScript)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter user names have the format `[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15}` so you in JavaScript you could do:

```
var url = 'https://twitter.com/StackExchange/stack-overflow-employees';
if( ! /\/([a-z0-9_]{1,15})\/(.+)$/i.exec( url ) ){
    throw new Error('Invalid list URL');
}
var userName = RegExp.$1, // = 'StackExchange'
    listSlug = RegExp.$2; // = 'stack-overflow-employees'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use RegEx, if you always have the URL in that format? You could just get the last part as a substring, then split it and get each part (this is using C#):

```
var userAndListName = "https://twitter.com/{list-owner-screen-name}/{list-slug}"
                         .Substring(20)
                         .Split('/');

var user = userAndListName.First();
var listName = userAndListName.Last();
```

Comment: this does not work when there are some parameters in the url `https://twitter.com/username?lang=de`